# laravel: глобальная переменная класса - можно ли?

Tags: laravel, классы

Доброе!
объявлен класс:

```
class Consumers extends Component
{
    public $organization_id, $org_name;

    public function render()    {
        $this->org_name = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organizations.name')
            ->value('organizations.name');

        return view('livewire.consumers');
    }

...
    public function store() {
        $this->validate([
            'name'              => 'required',
        ]);

        $this->org_name = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organizations.name')
            ->value('organizations.name');

        Consumer::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->serv_id], [
        ]);
}
```

как видите org_name приходится повторно запросом вытаскивать. А нельзя ли эту переменную вне функций инициализировать один раз и в них передавать?

Comment: попробовал так :public function __construct() {
        $this->org_name = DB::table('workers')
            ->select('organizations.name')
            ->value('organizations.name');
    } не передается параметр в другие методы (

Answer (score 0):

В соответствии с документацией https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties
You can initialize properties using the `mount` method of your component.